# MooEditable : temporary disable editing

Tags: html, css, iframe, mootools

I'm searching for a (simple ?) way to temporary disable my MooEditable block.

Using a `reset.css`, which put down some basic inline tag like `<strong>`, I would like to keep the MooEditable iframe style, without any possibility to edit the content (like a `<textarea disabled="disabled">`.

Not sure to be enought clear.

Comment: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: Of course not... A jsFiddle is useless here, I'm just asking for a general tip on Mootools, that's not a structural problem or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution, looking in the deepest files of MooEditable.

For people who maybee want this solution : MooEditable accepts options, then here's your calls :

```
$$('.mooeditable.enabled').mooEditable({enabled:true});
$$('.mooeditable.disabled').mooEditable({enabled:false});
```

You must modify a little bit of code, in the `attach` function :

```
attach: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.mode = 'iframe';
    this.editorDisabled = !this.options.enabled;
    ...
}
```

You can also (recommended) make the ui-toolbar hidden, adding a `hidden` class to :

```
MooEditable.UI.Toolbar= new Class({ 
    initialize: function(options){
        this.setOptions(options); 
        this.el = new Element('div', 
                              {'class': 'mooeditable-ui-toolbar ' + 
                                        (this.options.enabled ? '' : 'hidden') +
                                        this.options['class']
                              }); 
    } 
}
```

With of course the corresponding CSS :

```
.mooeditable-ui-toolbar.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please note that CKEditor natively supports this feature.